# can not re-register APNs after unregisterForRemoteNotification invoked

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I've a problem with register/unregister method in iOS.

My app will be register APNs when the user logged in and unregister APNs when the user logged out. It's work like perfect until...I saw a problem with unregister APNs method. Let's see step to reproduce this bug.

Step by step:

- Register APNs (Alert | Sound | Badge)
- Go to Notification Center -> turn off all app setting
- Unregister APNs (with unregisterForRemoteNotification method)

---> At now, we can not re-register APNs anymore :[

*FYI, When I come back Notification Center. Its seem to be a bug.*

[Notification Setting in device](http://i1049.photobucket.com/albums/s399/lvmtam/IMG_6945_zpsb24344af.png)

## MY QUESTION:

1. Have anyone saw it before?
2. Could you please to tell me the best way to unregister APNs in my case?

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying.  Are you saying that the call to unregister APNS fails once you turn off notifications in app settings or are you saying that if you subsequently re-enable the app settings in notification centre that you can't register in your app when it starts?

Comment: Hi Paulw11,
I'd already unregister APNs successful. But when I register APNs again, it doesn't call any delegate methods (fail or success).

Comment: But have you re-enabled the apps permissions at this point?

Comment: It doesn't work again too :[

Comment: FYI, I happen on iOS 7 only (I've tested it on iOS 6 & 7)

Comment: Have you tried on different devices?  From your image there is something messed up on that device

Comment: I tried it on iPhone 4s (iOS 7.0.4 & 6.0.1). Above image is iPad (iOS 7.0.4). It's seem to be happen only iOS 7.

Comment: I just tried it on my 7.1.2 iPhone 5s - no problems.  I am not sure why you are de-registering notifications though.  If the user logs out you should break the link between the device and their user on your server side, but I would leave the device settings unchanged.

Comment: Hi Paulw11,

Did you try re-register APNs after re-enable the app settings in notification centre, right?

Comment: Could you please tell me more about the steps which you conducted?

Comment: I've just updated iOS 7.1.2 and tested it. It's work. But If I can not re-enable the app settings. It still can not register APNs.

How do you know about it?

Comment: 1. Disable all settings in Notification Centre.  2. Call `unregisterForRemoteNotifications` 3. Go into settings - you do need to exit and go back in to notification centre at this point - and find your app at the bottom under 'DO NOT INCLUDE' and reenable settings. 4. Rerun app and login to call registerForRemoteNotifications again

Comment: I see, Paulw11.

We have to re-enable app setting to register APNs again.

The app workflow:
- Register APNs (device token) --> login with device token

The main point is : we know the problem here and re-enable app setting, but the user doesn't know it --> can not login

Do you have any advices for me in this case?

Comment: Why does failure to register for remote notification prevent a login?  The two should be unrelated. You should associate the device token with the login if you can, but it is bad design to require the device token.  What if the user declines notifications?

Comment: 1. >> The two should be unrelated.
I know but I need device token to push notification to client.
2. >> What if the user declines notifications?. 
The user can logged out to declines notifications.

Comment: I doubt that your app will pass review if it doesn't function without notifications enabled

Comment: My app passed apple review with APNs always push into client. But it seem to be inconvenient, so that i have to unregister APNs after the user logged out. 

If you were me, what should you do in this case? Please give me a advice, Paul :[ and sorry for my English

Comment: You should have a table in your server that holds the currently logged in user for each device token.  When a user logs out you can clear the association for that device. When you send pushes you should only send them to devices that currently have uses logged in.  What happens if the user denies the initial push notification request.  Login should not be tied to push notification

Comment: Oh that's a good idea. One more question, Paul. Could you re-register APNs with disable all app setting? It's a iOS bug or I do something wrong?

Comment: If all notification options are disabled then neither of the registration call back (success or fail) methods are invoked

Comment: I understand, Paul. Thank you so much for your great answer :] You're my hero haha